# Three part authentication

Tags: c#, session, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a site whereby the user comes along and registers, the registration has three parts as follows

1. Part 1 : User chooses a username, enters email, DOB. Then presses submit and gets directed to Part 2
2. Part 2 : User enters additional information about her/her self. The presses submit and gets directed to Part 3
3. Part 3 : User has the option to upload images. Then presses submit

After Part 3 I then authenticate the user and log them in, the problem I'm trying to figure out is when they are going from Part 1 to Part 3 I need to keep a track of it so after Part 1 I will save the values in the database and return a UniqueId for that user and store this in the session and refer to it in part 2 and 3, I've had a few issues with sessions in the past whereby it times out I'm trying to think of a concrete solution to use instead of session. I did try Googling this but to see if anyone else in the world has done something similar but with no luck, hence why I have decided to ask this on here.

Comment: You could return the value to the user in the form of a cookie or a hidden form value.  That way the state of who the user is would be kept by the user, not by the web server.  When the user submits the request for the next step, that request would carry the ID with it.  (And if it doesn't, the server would just start the user over again.)  Unless *absolutely* necessary, I'd avoid maintaining any state in web server session.  Let the state be carried by the page or the database.

Comment: @David seems like a good idea, I was swaying more towards a cookie, but I think the hidden field could be a better solution that way I can pass it from controller 1 to controller 3.

Comment: A cookie would accomplish the same thing.  It all comes down to what sort of user experience you're expecting.  If the user is expected to go through the entire process in one session, keeping it on the page as a form value is fine.  If the user can be expected to abandon the session, close their browser, and come back later to return where they left off then a cookie would be more appropriate.  That doesn't seem like a likely use case for just registering on a website though.

Comment: @David Well I'm hoping they will just register all the way through, each part has its own status i.e 1,2,3 so even if they go to part 2 and decided to close the browser and come back later and try signing it I will check to see if they have completed the registration section if not depending on the status will determine what part they are sent to.

Comment: If you want them to be able to return where they left off then the server will need the identifier value.  So it would need to be kept in a cookie that way it will persist after closing the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use cookies to store the user's progress if you want them to be able to close the browser and continue later. It's difficult to give an exact solution without knowing your full project but this should definitely help you.

```
public ActionResult Signup()
    {
        //The cookie could be stored in the format: partnumber_databaseid
        //An example cookie would look like 1_24
        if (request.Cookies["SingupProgress"] != null)
        {
            var part = request.Cookies["SignupProgress"].ToString().Split('_')[0];
            var id = request.Cookies["SignupProgress"].ToString().Split('_')[1];

            //Eg if the cookie stored number "1" as part, the returned view would be "Part2"
            //Return the stored part number plus one, as the part number will represent which part they have already completed
            string ViewName = "Part" + part + 1;

            return View(ViewName);
        }
        else
        {
            //If the cookie doesn't exist, that means the user has not made any sign up progress
            //Direct them to the first signup part
            return View("Part1");
        }

    }

    public ActionResult Part2()
    {
        //Direct the user to this action once they have clicked next on the Part 1 view

        //Create the class to store the progress data.
        //You also need this to extract the Unique ID for the cookie
        ProgressClass Progress = new ProgressClass(/*Your data*/);

        //Store the progress into the database
        db.StoreProgressData();
        db.Save();

        //Get the unique ID that you just saved into the database

        int Id = Progress.Id;

        HttpCookie ProgressCookie = new HttpCookie("SignupProgress", Id + "_2");
    }

    //Once they reach part 3 your final link can direct them to a register action, which creates the account and saves it to a database
```